# Using linq to compare object values works for single object but not a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two methods I am using to return a subset or filtered list of objects based on a supplied keyname and keyvalue. The first method, which is passed a single keyname and keyvalue works correctly, but the second method that is passed a keyname and a List of potential values always returns an empty list.  Can anyone help with the syntax of the second method and let me know what I am doing wrong?

This one works:

```
public List<GenericDataObject> FilterItems(string ItemStatus, string KeyName, object KeyValue)
    {
        return this.Items.Where(p => p.PropString("ItemStatus") == ItemStatus && p.Prop(KeyName).Equals(KeyValue)).ToList();
    }
```

This one does not:

```
public List<GenericDataObject> FilterItems(string ItemStatus, string KeyName, List<object> KeyValues)
    {
        return this.Items.Where(p => p.PropString("ItemStatus") == ItemStatus && KeyValues.Contains(p.Prop(KeyName))).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: could you post the code you tried with the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

simply rewrite your condition into this

```
KeyValues.Any(x => x.Equals(p.Prop(KeyName)))
```

Comment: isn't this the same result with using `Contains`?

Comment: I am a bit unclear on where to put this... I have the entire line as this now and still get no results:
return this.Items.Where(p => p.PropString("ItemStatus") == ItemStatus && KeyValues.Any(x => x.Equals(p.Prop(KeyName)))).ToList();

Comment: What declared type and real type is returns from your p.Prop method?

Comment: the declared and returned type are object.

public object Prop(string KeyName)
        {
            if (this.ContainsKey(KeyName)) return this[KeyName].Value;
            else return null;
        }

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But what about "real" types of this data? Looks like objects in your list have different type from data in your p.Prop() call result. For example p.Prop() call returns long and list of objects contains ints.

Comment: I determined that in my calling code I was passing the method a list of strings instead of a list of objects... that would make the object comparison not work.  I have added an overload method that allows a List<string> parameter as well to prevent this mistake from happening again.  Thanks for all of the responses.